# a good way to preaload audio files using openAL in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, openal

I'm making a game for iOS platform and i want to use openAL for playing audio effects in the game (except the background music). I want to have for example 20-30 sounds with duration of 1-3 seconds each. Because i want these sounds to be played with no delay i have to load from file, decompress and store in the memory. But decompressed audio (as i understand) uses a lot of memory. So am I on the right way? Or there is another way ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading sounds does incur a delay, and can cause the rest of the app to jitter. For best performance you definitely want to preload sound effects.

Memory use is a concern, but as long as you're not loading too much audio data into memory at a time, you'll be OK.

44KHz mono audio data will occupy 88,000 bytes per second when uncompressed. Stereo is double that, but usually for sound effects you don't want stereo anyway. So if you had 30 sounds loaded, each of 3 second duration, you'd have 90 seconds of sound using 7.5MB of memory. You can of course halve that memory usage by using a 22050 Hz source before compressing it to AAC (which preserves the source sample rate).

What I do is maintain a cache of audio buffers that I can flush when the app starts to use too much memory like so: https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/blob/master/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OALSimpleAudio.m#L441

Answer (score 1):

For the lowest latency sound effects, you will want to play uncompressed audio already in memory.  2 or 3 MBytes is not a lot of memory to allocate for low latency sound effects.